# Как сделать свой сборщик мусора сессий?

Tags: сессия, php

Как сделать свой сборщик мусора сессий при помощи session_set_save_handler не используя при этом другие callback  функции такие как open, write, и т.д.

> **Ответившего на вопрос ждет небольшое вознаграждение!**

Comment: какие переменные вы о чем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать свой класс, производный от [`SessionHandler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php). В нем реализовать свой GC, остальные методы не переопределять. Класс или его инстанцию передать `session_set_save_handler`.

Работать будет только с PHP 5.4 и выше, где появилась соответствующая инфраструктура для этого. В более старых версиях — никак, там реализации стандартных функций чтения/записи/… не доступны из языка.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы храните сессии в базе (SQL), то достаточно периодически (используя любой планировщик) очищать базу от устаревших сессий

```
DELETE FROM `таблица_с_сессиями` WHERE `время_последнего_доступа` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1440 SECOND)
```

UPD.
А в чём храните?

Если в файлах, то тогда гляньте [как это реализовано в убунте](http://webenterprise.ru/remove-old-php-sessions-in-debian/). По крону срабатывает задача, удаляющая файлы сессий старше определённого времени. Эта задача использует вспомогательный скрипт, получающий значение session.gc_maxlifetime из php.ini.

Comment: я не храню сесси в БД